Как убрать надписи с робочего стола
на служебном компе такие надписи. Может кто знает как убрать, потому что как соринка в глазу(
Пробовал через редактор регистра в HKEY CORENT US - CONTROL PANEL -  desctop - paintdescopversion
безрезультатно так как это не пробная версия виндовс

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Откройте редактор реестра: нажмите Win + R, чтобы открыть окно "Выполнить", введите regedit и нажмите Enter.
Перейдите к нужному разделу:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop.
Измените значение параметра:
найдите параметр PaintDesktopVersion, дважды щелкните по нему и измените значение на 0, чтобы выключить отображение надписей.
Закройте редактор реестра и перезагрузите компьютер, чтобы изменения вступили в силу.
Причина появления: скорее всего текущая версия устанавливалась наверх тестовой сборки при участии в инсайдерской программе тестирования.
Я бы переустановил этот мусорник, будет быстрее.

в этом и прблема что это уже пробовал, у меня там 0. Ноут фирмы по этому не могу переустановить.

Меня терзают смутные сомнения насчёт качества и аккуратности. Например: HKEY CORENT US - CONTROL PANEL - desctop - paintdescopversion. Ничего не подозреваете? А ещё что у меня есть, а у Вас нет? Слово, выделенное жирным шрифтом: перезагрузите.

Специально для Вас, прямо в эту минуту, лично я включил эти надписи, перезагрузил комп, увидел их, затем выключил, перезагрузил и не увидел их. Делалось это в Windows 11 24H2. Если Вас это раздражает, но Вы не можете исправить, вызовите того, кто может, а ещё лучше пусть Вам установят как следует Windows. Вариант, который я тут показал, работает. Естественно, при условии, что ОС не разбита до невозможности, грамотно установлена и операции выполняются квалифицированным специалистом.
